# Using an autoencoder for anomaly detection on categorical data

Tags: neural-network, anomaly-detection, autoencoder

Say a dataset has 0.5% of its features continuous and 99.5% categorical (binary) with ~2400 features in total. In this dataset, each observation is 1 of 2 classes - **Fraud (1)** or **Not Fraud (0)**. Furthermore, there is a large class imbalance with only 2.6% of examples being Fraud, and the other ~97% of examples being Not Fraud.

Say we want to to predict whether a given example is Fraud or Not Fraud, and we take an anomaly detection approach using autoencoders.

Given the mixed data types in the dataset, in general, will an autoencoder, **trained on only the Non Fraud examples**, perform well in predicting Fraud examples? Is there any literature to suggest what architectures work best / if some preprocessing should be performed beforehand (scaling and PCA)? I ask because I feel an autoencoder may be hard to train with binary features.

Comment: Is there any chance that you train it also on Fraud examples? They are quite important part of the equation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general an autoencoder should perform well, when it comes to detect fraud examples. Fraud examples should have in theory a much higher reconstruction error. 
When it comes to train the autoencoder on binary data, I agree with you that it can be quite challenging. I suggest to take a look at this blog:
https://blog.evjang.com/2016/11/tutorial-categorical-variational.html